# Increment the int value of a field by one in Firestore database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have this code:

```
let brandDocRef = self.database.collection("Companies").document("Nike")
brandDocRef.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapshot, error in
    guard let data = snapshot?.data(), error == nil else {
        return
    }
    if let clientsValue = data["Clients"] as? Int {
       clientsValue = clientsValue + 1                       
      
        let clientData: [String: Int] = [
        "Clients": clientsValue
        ]
        brandDocRef!.setData(brandData, merge: true) { error in
        if let error = error { } else { }
  }
```

This code is supposed to go into my firestore database, get the value in the "clients" field in the "Nike" document, then increment it by one, and update the value in the document. But as it is a `snapshotListener`, the value of `clientsValue` changes and the function gets called another time. And this creates an infinite loop; and it increments the value over and over. How can I avoid this loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read-and-increment the value only once, use the [`getDocument` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift_2) rather than `addSnapshotListener`. This will read the data only once, so there won't be a loop.